# OnOpen formula to place google sheet ID into cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, loading, custom-function

I am currently using this formula to get the id:

```
function getId() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
}
```

It works fine, I just use the formula in a cell to pull the id.  Problem is sometimes it takes forever and gets stuck on `"loading"` when I make a duplicate of the sheet.  Is there an onopen formula I can use to place the sheet id value in a specific cell without using the formula `=getid()` in the cell of the sheet?  Will that prevent the constant loading problem or am I just creating the same problem again?

Comment: You should read about [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=en) they have restrictions and limitations.  Currently you are using them inappropriately

Comment: That function would work just fine if it were run from the script editor and you called it from another function that displayed the return value

Comment: I don't see that as hateful.  It is kind of a pointless thing to do because you can't use that id to do anything else with in the script like opening the spreadsheet because that's not allowed in custom functions.  So why go down that path what's the point what are you trying to accomplish what's your goal.

Comment: I noticed how you removed the comment saying what I'm trying to do is dumb.  All I'm trying to do is input the current sheet ID value into a cell because it's used to import ranges from a master sheet.  I have been looking for a script that I can create an onopen trigger for to input the current sheet ID value into cell Z3 of the sheet titled "IMPORT".  That's it.

Answer (score 0):

#### A function to load the id of spreadsheet into Z3 when spreadsheet opens

```
function onOpen() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getRange('Z3').setValue(ss.getId());
}
```

[Range.setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: I didn't know do you have a reference I'd like read that.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I've that wrong for a long time.

Comment: @TheMaster I seem to remember a time when that did not work but it does now.